# Extjs boxselect issue

Tags: extjs4

i am working in extjs4. i have 'boxselect' as xtype with following configuration=

```
  xtype: 'boxselect',
            emptyText: Email
            store: store,
            displayField: 'emailAddress',
            width: 500,
            height: 40,
            valueField: 'emailAddress',
            queryMode: 'local',
            allowBlank: false,
        submitValue: false,
```

But when this box is rendering,it already appearing with red border to user. If user not will not entered email and proceed ahead then only i want to show it in rec block. So how to remove this red border of required intially during rendering

Comment: missing comma after Email. is Email a local variable?

Comment: you are doing something funky, it should not do what you are seeing. perhaps you already called setValues or focused on the field?